# Segmentation fault in C pipe that call gnuplot

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gnuplot

I wrote this function for write data on file and use them to print graphics with gnuplot.

```
void write_data_on_file_lagrange(double *x_node, double *y_node, double *x_val, double *poly, double *err){

int i;

char *gnuplot_commands[] = {"set title \"INTERPOLAZIONE DI ln(x+1) + 

cos(x-1) TRAMITE POLINOMIO DI LAGRANGE\"", 
                                "plot 'Resources/function.txt' title 'Reale' smooth csplines, 'Resources/lagrange.txt' title 'Interpolata' smooth csplines, 'Resources/error_lagrange.txt' title 'Errore' smooth csplines"};

    FILE *file  = fopen("Resources/function.txt", "w");
    FILE *file1 = fopen("Resources/lagrange.txt", "w");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("Resources/error_lagrange.txt", "w");
    FILE *pipe  = popen("gnuplot -p", "w");

    if(file == NULL || file1 == NULL || file2 == NULL){
        perror("Errore nell'apertura del file!\n");
        abort();
    }

    if(pipe == NULL){
        perror("Errore nella creazione della pipe!\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++)  fprintf(file, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_node[i], y_node[i]);

    fprintf(file1, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_node[0], y_node[0]);
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++)   fprintf(file1, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_val[i], poly[i]);
    fprintf(file1, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_node[GRADE], y_node[GRADE]);

    fprintf(file2, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_node[0], 0);
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++)   fprintf(file2, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_val[i], err[i]);
    fprintf(file2, "%.4f %.4f\n", x_node[GRADE], 0);

    fclose(file);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    for (i = 0; i < COMMANDS; i++) fprintf(pipe, "%s \n", gnuplot_commands[i]);

    pclose(pipe);
}
```

I do not understand why this function when the call is never executed and goes into segmentation fault.

In addition to the code of the function's call, I put the code to calculate the other arrays. The function above is not even performed. This happens to me with Debian, Fedora and Mac work without problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GRADE 6

char *separator = "";
double xNode[GRADE + 1], xVal[GRADE], yNode[GRADE + 1];
double *poly, *err;

double* polynomial_lagrange(const double *x_val, const double *x_node, const double *y_node){
    int i, j, k;
    double pr, *sum = (double *) malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));

    for(j = 0; j < GRADE; j++){
        sum[j] = 0.0;
        for(k = 0; k < GRADE + 1; k++){
            pr = 1;
            for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
                if(k != i)
                    pr = pr * ((x_val[j] - x_node[i])/(x_node[k] - x_node[i]));
            }
            sum[j] = sum[j] + y_node[k] * pr;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
double* error_lagrange(const double *x_val, const double *sum){

    int i;
    double *err = (double *) malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));

    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++) 
        err[i] = fabs(((log(x_val[i] + 1)) + cos(x_val[i] - 1)) - sum[i]);

    return err;
}

int main(void){

    printf("X_NODE     {");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
        x_node[i] = i;
        printf("%s%.4f", separator, x_node[i]);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    printf("}\n");

    separator = "";
    printf("Y_NODE     {");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
        y_node[i] = log(x_node[i] + 1) + cos(x_node[i] - 1);
        printf("%s%.4f", separator, y_node[i]);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    printf("}\n");

    separator = "";
    printf("X_VALUE    {");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++){
        x_val[i] = (x_node[i] + x_node[i+1]) / 2;
        printf("%s%.4f", separator, x_val[i]);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    printf("}\n");

    poly = polynomial_lagrange(xVal, xNode, yNode);
    err = error_lagrange(xVal, poly);

    write_data_on_file_lagrange(xNode, yNode, xVal, poly, err);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The critical part  - the caller, is missing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just edited the question. Sorry!

Comment: What's `COMMANDS`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. #define COMMANDS 2

Comment: I would suggest you to get rid of dynamic allocation for `err` and `poly` and have them allocated the same ways as `x_node` and friends. Can't see a problem from just looking anyway

Comment: @EugeneSh. I testing the code with valgrind and there aren't memory leak. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall` and remove all warnings. You will get: *warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'int'*